# How is lunar regolith drawn into "glass fibers" to reinforce lunar concrete in this process?

Tags: colonization, materials

The Verge Science video [Building a lunar base out of Moon dust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0TPJQSmAHU) discusses using harvested lunar regolith (powder-like) mixed with a polymeric resin produced from "space trash" (I'm imagining discarded plastic food pouches for example) to make a structural material that can be 3D printed for building.

Starting at `04:12`:

> So you mush it together in a very specific mixture ratio, and what you get is a polymer composite concrete. And so you can make that polymer composite concrete either using the granular material right off the ground, or you can heat up and draw out that granular material into a glass fiber. and then if you use the glass fiber, it makes the material really strong, like carbon fiber or kevlar.

What does the process of converting regolith to glass fiber look like? Is it done in a tower, like drawing optical fiber, or squeezing molten rock through a mesh of tiny holes? Something else?

Comment: May be a similar process to make [Mineral Wool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_wool) may be used.

Comment: From @Uwe's link "More advanced production techniques are based on spinning molten rock in high-speed spinning heads somewhat like the process used to produce cotton candy" but cooling the material may be a problem

Comment: So should this work, will Earth be exporting its plastic trash towards Luna in exchange for He3-rich regolith? That's the start of another scifi novel..

Comment: @JCRM this was sounding familliar, then I remembered [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/84958/can-stone-be-recycled-by-melting-and-cooling-it/84965#comment250239_84965). Searching stone wool, rock wool and mineral wool finds a lot of resources, but they seem to start with known-low-melting point materials like solidified lava. (more YouTubes: [1](https://youtu.be/KrfWe1mLGzc), [2](https://youtu.be/4aGOAIScs0o), [3](https://youtu.be/rOmbuZ7VyFo), [4](https://youtu.be/OPROLTGK_0g))

Comment: Glas wool is made on Earth too requiring the relative high temperature of molten glas. Molten lunar regolith may be similar to molten glas.

Comment: @Uwe I finally found what I was thinking of, it only took *eleven months!* rockwool/mineral wool: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_wool), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt_fiber), [3](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/84965/40033), [4](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/60256/40033), [5](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/106062/40033), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6FWPTZjwLo Please feel free to put together an answer if you're interested.  **update:** oh, many of these I already posted above, oh well.